# Find the smallest number from a row in a matrix filtered by a value in a data frame?

Tags: r, geospatial, distance

I have a dataset of locations, and I am trying to find the distance to the closest metro area. Sample:

```
library(SpatialEpi)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(100124, 100460, 100484, 100676, 100820, 2608640), c(2563, 4325, 637,330, 15278, 209880), c(31.56795, 33.60575, 34.20269, 32.87949, 33.24476, 33.52775), c(-85.25130, -86.94917, -87.17785, -87.73878, -86.76102, -86.79905), c(0,0,0,0,0,1)))
colnames(df) <- c("GEOID", "population", "latitude", "longitude", "is_metro")
```

I created a distance matrix using `dist`

`df_dist <- as.matrix(dist(latlong2grid(matrix(c(df$longitude, df$latitude), ncol = 2, nrow=nrow(df)))))`

Now I would like for each row to return the distance to the closest value where is_metro=1. So, for example below, in row 1, the closest value is the 5th column, but I want to return the 6th column because that is the the column where the equivalent row is `is_metro==1`. For this particular example, I would need all of these rows to show the relevant distance to row 6, but in the full dataset, I have nearly 20K records and many records where `is_metro==1`, and I would need the closest one.

[image]

I hope that all makes sense. Where do I even start?

Comment: I guess in this dataset, you simply need the 6th column.  Can you modify the example with a general case where there are many is_metro = 1 and the expected output

Comment: Or with a slight change `df$is_metro[3] <- 1` what would be the expected output for this example

Comment: @akrun I will choose a different row, so it could return a different value.  if ```df$is_metro[2] <- 1``` then for ```df$closest_metro[1] <- 256.0408``` and for ```df$closest_metro[3] <- 69.25702```

Comment: What would be your expected output `tmp <- (NA^!df$is_metro[col(df_dist)]) * df_dist;max.col(-replace(tmp, is.na(tmp), Inf), 'first')
[1] 6 2 2 2 6 6`

Comment: `df_dist[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df_dist)), max.col(-replace(tmp, is.na(tmp), Inf), 'first'))]
[1] 256.04080   0.00000  69.25702 105.97461  31.62297   0.00000`

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand the question. If we change the inputs to be ```df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(100124, 100460, 100484, 100676, 100820, 2608640), c(2563, 4325, 637,330, 15278, 209880), c(31.56795, 33.60575, 34.20269, 32.87949, 33.24476, 33.52775), c(-85.25130, -86.94917, -87.17785, -87.73878, -86.76102, -86.79905), c(0,1,0,0,0,1)))
```, then the expected output would ideally be ```df$closest_metro <- c(256.04080, 0, 69.25702, 105.97461, 31.62297, 0)```

Comment: Can you please check my solution posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col` on the negative transformed `df_dist` after setting the values  in columns that are 0 for 'is_metro' to 'Inf'.  The `max.col` will get the index of the maximum value (by changing it to negative `-`, it gives the index of min value) and then extract the values with a row/column index

```
tmp <- (NA^!df$is_metro[col(df_dist)]) * df_dist
df_dist[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df_dist)), 
         max.col(-replace(tmp, is.na(tmp), Inf), 'first'))]
```

---

Or another option is `pmin`

```
df$closest_metro  <- do.call(pmin, c(asplit(tmp, 2), na.rm = TRUE))
df$closest_metro 
#[1] 256.04080   0.00000  69.25702 105.97461  31.62297   0.00000
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(GEOID = c(100124, 100460, 100484, 100676, 100820, 
2608640), population = c(2563, 4325, 637, 330, 15278, 209880), 
    latitude = c(31.56795, 33.60575, 34.20269, 32.87949, 33.24476, 
    33.52775), longitude = c(-85.2513, -86.94917, -87.17785, 
    -87.73878, -86.76102, -86.79905), is_metro = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```